# Optimization of OpenCV on android (neon-instruction, GLSL on tegra 3 )

Tags: android, opencv, acceleration

I am now using some OpenCV functions in my Android application development. Since the frame rate is quite critical for the program, I am wondering how could I enable the optimization of OpenCV on android, since I have read about the newest version (2.4) of OpenCV use neon-instruction and GLSL for acceleration, is it automatically enabled? Or anything I need to put in the Android.mk file for compiling? 
(P.S. the Opencv Manager on android automatically download the "OCV 2.4 pack NVIDIA Tegra 3" alr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "OCV 2.4 pack NVIDIA Tegra 3" package contains NEON and GLSL optimizations of OpenCV.

If you use OpenCV Manager API for OpenCV initialization it uses the optimized libs automatically.

Comment: Do those NEON and GLSL optimizations work only with Tegra 3 chips? Or it will work with any chip supporting NEON and/or GLSL? Besides to utilise GLSL do I have to use cv::gpu module or cv:: module can also reap benefit of GLSL?

Comment: >>Do those NEON and GLSL optimizations work only with Tegra 3 chips? Or it will work with any chip supporting NEON and/or GLSL?
<br>
[O4A] These optimizations work on Tegra 3 only, until NVidia contribute them to opensource one day...
<br>
<br>
>>Besides to utilise GLSL do I have to use cv::gpu module or cv:: module can also reap benefit of GLSL?
<br>
[O4A] The cv::gpu module is implemented with CUDA which isn't supported on Tegra platform currently.