# OpenCV optimization for Tegra 2

Tags: android, opencv, glsl, tegra

In my search of trying to find a way of implementing some computer vision algorithms on the GPU of a tablet, I came across the OCV 2.4 pack NVIDIA Tegra 3. From this post: [Optimization of OpenCV on android (neon-instruction, GLSL on tegra 3 )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561462/optimization-of-opencv-on-android-neon-instruction-glsl-on-tegra-3?rq=1) I understood that this OpenCV pack contains GLSL and NEON optimizations for NVIDIA Tegra 3. Does anybody know if there is such an OpenCV pack with optimizations for Tegra 2? My tablet has Android 3.1 as operating system.

Comment: So my only solution is to implement the algorithms in GLSL myself?

Answer (score 1):

From the [very important paper](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2206309), neon instruction is not supported by tegra 2, so I think acceleration on CPU parallelism of OpenCV is not on tegra 2. For GPU acceleration, I suppose that as long as OpenGL ES 2.0 is supported on Tegra 2, so I think it is enabled.